# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha, gulp-karma

**This is my Js code**

```
(function () {
angular.module('app',[])
    .factory('code', function ($http, svc, $q) {
     function getCodeByID(id) {
            return $http.get(svc.get('my-application') + id)
                .then(function (res) {
                    return res;
                });
        }
    })
})();
```

**This is my Spec.js file**

```
 describe('MyController', function() {
var data, svc, code;
// Set up the module
//beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_data_) {
    data = _data_;
}));
beforeEach(inject(function(_svc_) {
    svc = _svc_;
}));
beforeEach(inject(function(_code_) {
    code = _code_;
}));
it('Should exist', function() {
    expect(code).toBeDefined();
});});
```

Getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data
    https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.4/$injector/unpr?p0=dataProvider%20%3C-%20data
        at node_modules/angular/angular.js:138:12
        at node_modules/angular/angular.js:4905:19
        at Object.getService [as get] (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5065:32)
        at node_modules/angular/angular.js:4910:45
        at getService (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5065:32)
        at injectionArgs (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5090:58)
        at Object.invoke (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5114:18)
        at UserContext.WorkFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3439:20)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3402:25)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (src/app/epcCodes/epc.spec.js:9:16)
        at src/app/epcCodes/epc.spec.js:2:1
```

I don't know why I am getting this error, I have added all the dependency injection that's needed for my project.
Can you provide me the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need one of those `beforeEach` blocks where you are injecting your services -- though this has nothing to do with your issue.
2. This one does have to do with your issue -- you are "telling" your test to inject a `data` component/service/factory when one apparently does not exist in your code. What are you expecting `data` to be?

Comment: Here, I am using the dependency svc to inject in my code.
This function also included in .js file.

Comment: `  function getCodes(query) {
                var qry = ccUtils.buildQuery(query);
                return $http.get(svc.get('url')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        var resObj = {};
                        resObj.data = response.data.content;
                        resObj.pageData = {
                            totalPages: response.data.totalPages,
                            totalElements: response.data.totalElements
                        };
                        return resObj;
                    })
            }
`

Comment: Can anyone help me in this issue

Comment: If you want people to help you, you really should post ALL of the relevant code in your original post. If you want help, make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: I have added my index.js and svc.js file in this post

Comment: Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('Svc', [])
.factory('Svc', function (Data, $injector, $http) {
    var ConfigData = Data;
    var Svc = {};
    Svc.get = function (key) {
        return ConfigData[key];
    };
    Svc.loadResourcePaths = function (resources) {
        resources.forEach(function (resource) {
            $http.get(Svc.get('security-api') + 'resources?name=' + resource)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.totalElements === 1) {
                        ConfigData[resource] = response.data.content[0].href;
                    } else {
                    }
                })
        })
    };
    return Svc;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
angular
    .module('app', [
        'ConfigSvc',
        'AuthUtils',
        'ngCsv'
    ])

    .constant('APPNAME', 'ui')
    .constant('APPLABEL', 'app_label')
    .constant('APPPREFIX', 'App_name')

    .config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('grey', {'default': '900'})
            .accentPalette('blue', {'default': '400'})
        ;
    })
    .config(function routesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $mdAriaProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                template: '<app></app>',
                data: {
                    label: 'Home',
                    icon: 'home',
                    menu: true
                }
            });
    });


angular.element(document).ready(function () {

    var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

    $http.get('appConfig.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            angular.module('app').constant('Data', response.data);

            return $http.get('appFeatures.json')
        })
        .then(function (response) {

            angular.module('app').constant('ccAppFeatures', response.data);
        })
        .finally(function () {

            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
});})();
```

Comment: This is my index.js file